# MySQL - LEFT JOIN - How do it get the value that i need

Tags: php, mysql, select, left-join

i have three tables: "playerstat", "player" and "game".

the "playerstat" table is empty at the first time, the "players" already have a choice of players and the table "game" also has an entry where the stats and the players can be assigned.
 
now i want that the players with the related stats should be listed. you can give each player points or other stats. that already works.

the entries in the "playerstat" (each player is here automatically as soon as data like points is filled in) and "game" table have one and the same relations code. the players have no relation code, because the game is always changing but the player remains the same.

my problem is that if a game is completed and a new game started and i put in data to the player then the points etc are again in the first gamestats. so the new data for the second game are added to the stats from the first game.

how do i get that the points are added to the respective stats that also had the relations code of game and stats?

here is my query:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT 
lt_player.name, lt_player.surname, lt_player.nickname, 
lt_player.number, lt_player.id as playerid, 
lt_playerstat.points, lt_playerstat.team_id, 
lt_playerstat.rel_code 
FROM
lt_player
LEFT JOIN lt_playerstat ON (lt_player.id = lt_playerstat.playerid)
```

what i actually need is a "WHERE lt_playerstat.rel_code = 'lt_game.rel_code'" and at the same time all available players. how can i do this?

here are my tables:

playerstats
  `id`
  `game_id`
  `team_id`
  `playerid`
  `points`
  `active` 
  `rel_code`

player
  `id`
  `team_id`
  `name`
  `surname`
  `nickname`
  `number`

game
  `id` 
  `team_id`
  `date`
  `time`
  `rel_code`

first game stats "denny doodle" has 4 points
[image]

second game stats "denny doodle" has again 4 points because thats the stat of the first game and not the second because the relation to the game is missing i guess.
[image]
it shows all entries even its not the real_code of the current game.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps sample data and desired results would make this easier to understand.  If you want on those payers also in the games table matching on the `rel_code` field, you can add an `inner join` to the `lt_game` table.

Comment: The relations are unclear, but as I see it, you should have a table 'playergame', that stores the outcome of a game per player. It should refer to the game and to a player, and hold the score of that player in the game. Then, if you want stats for a game, you can query all playergame rows for that game. If you want stats for the player, you can query all rows for that player. I'm not sure your current playerstats table provides this.

Comment: thank you for your answers. i updated my post with my tables.
@sgeddes the players have no relation that matches with the game only the team_id but this is always the same for the player who plays in that team so its not unique.

Comment: Can you show some sample data too (spaces for alignment, not tabs), and also from that, what you would EXPECT to get for results.. especially for total points, comparison of player's code = game's code, then you also mention who plays in the team...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know what the rel_code is of the current game:

```
SELECT 
lt_player.name, lt_player.surname, lt_player.nickname, 
lt_player.number, lt_player.id as playerid, 
lt_playerstat.points, lt_playerstat.team_id, 
lt_playerstat.rel_code 
FROM
lt_player
INNER JOIN lt_game
LEFT JOIN lt_playerstat ON (lt_playerstat.playerid = lt_player.id)
where lt_game.rel_code = 'The Rel Code Of the Current Game'
```

If you want to sum the score for each player in the game

```
SELECT 
lt_player.name, lt_player.surname, lt_player.nickname, 
lt_player.number, lt_player.id as playerid, 
sum(lt_playerstat.points), lt_playerstat.team_id, 
lt_playerstat.rel_code 
FROM
lt_player
INNER JOIN lt_game
LEFT JOIN lt_playerstat ON (lt_playerstat.playerid = lt_player.id)
where lt_game.rel_code = 'The Rel Code Of the Current Game'
group by lt_player.id
```

If you do not know the rel_code of the current game, then you cannot do it afaik.

Not sure what you mean by "all available players" but this will give you the player_stat for all players that have a player_stat row and the correct rel_code.

Comment: thank you. i have the rel_code of the game but there are no players in the player_stat at the first time, they just appear after you put in a stat for the player who is listed. with your solution there is no player listed to add stats because there is no row for the player in the player_stat. i need to list all players at anytime to put in stats even there is no row in the player_stat. i need something like if no players in the player_stat then list player from the player table.

Comment: i need something like if no players row in the player_stat then list players from the player table.

Comment: That's exactly what this will do.  A LEFT JOIN in MySql will return the rows for the left table, which in this case is `Players`, even if there is no matching row in the right table (`lt_playerstat`).  Also, I edited the query to make lt_game an inner join, as it is always required to have a row.

Comment: thank you evan. this showing me all the records and players but when i add points to a player in another game it will also shown the points of the game that is not the game that is shown. it takes all the points that have been made in all games. i added another picture to my question too show you what i mean. maybe i need two while loops?

Comment: I edited the original example to not show the points from other games.  I also added a new example that will aggregate the points per user, for the specified game (rel_code).  Try out these two examples and see if one of them gives you what you need.

Comment: hey evan! i solved the problem. thank u a lot for your support! :) 
what i've done is delete the where clause and added "LEFT JOIN lt_playerstat ON (lt_playerstat.playerid = lt_player.id AND lt_playerstat.rel_code = '$gameid')" and now it works.